# Tensorflow - How to compare 2 checkpoints?

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers

Assume I have two Tensorflow models saved with `tf.train.Saver()`, `chkp1` and `chkp2`.

Unfortunately, I don't have the original code to place the graphs, is it possible to compare the two networks? Something like `diff` between them?

I am not looking for the weights diff but for the graph structure diff.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a diff function but you can load them into tensorboard and view the graphs. If you are using anaconda you can open the anaconda prompt and enter

```
tensorboard --logdir=<path_to_file_containing_checkpoints>
```

As long as you have the .meta files saved you will be able to view the graph from each run.

Comment: I am well aware of tensorboard and using it, however my 2 networks are huge and manually comparing the two visual graphs is exactly what I am trying to avoid.